# Array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C

Tags: swift

I have this code that creates a view and applies a gradient to it.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


let rect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)

var vista : UIView = UIView(frame: rect)

let gradient : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = vista.bounds

let cor1 = UIColor.blackColor()
let cor2 = UIColor.whiteColor()

let arrayColors = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]

gradient.colors = arrayColors

view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex:0)
```

Xcode is giving me no compile error, but the code is crashing on the line

```
let arrayColors = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]
```

with the message **array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C**

In fact I was expecting it to crash there, because I am not sure how I can create an array of CGColors on Swift. The surprise here is Xcode mentioning Objective-C. In my mind I was creating a CGColorRef in swift...

Any clues? Why is it mentioning Objective-C and how do I solve this?

Comment: its work for me, two option:
1. try to do "let arrayColors: NSArray = ....
2. try to clean your project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24997536/2446155

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason Objective-C is mentioned is because UIKit and QuartzCore are Objective-C frameworks. In particular, `gradient.colors = arrayColors` is calling an Objective-C method that expects an `NSArray`.

This seems like a bug, as Apple's documentation makes it sound like that the array should auto-bridge to an `NSArray` so long as the items in the array can be considered `AnyObject`:

> When you bridge from a Swift array to an NSArray object, the elements
>   in the Swift array must be AnyObject compatible. For example, a Swift
>   array of type Int[] contains Int structure elements. The Int type is
>   not an instance of a class, but because the Int type bridges to the
>   NSNumber class, the Int type is AnyObject compatible. Therefore, you
>   can bridge a Swift array of type Int[] to an NSArray object. If an
>   element in a Swift array is not AnyObject compatible, a runtime error
>   occurs when you bridge to an NSArray object.
>
> You can also create an NSArray object directly from a Swift array literal, following the same bridging rules outlined above. When you
>   explicitly type a constant or variable as an NSArray object and assign
>   it an array literal, Swift creates an NSArray object instead of a
>   Swift array.

For now, a work around would be either to declare `arrayColors` as an `NSArray`:

`let arrayColors: NSArray = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]`

Or to declare it as taking `AnyObject`:

`let arrayColors: Array <AnyObject> = [cor1.CGColor, cor2.CGColor]`

Comment: ah, I see. I did not understand the second line of code. What are you saying there? make me an array where every element is <AnyObject>? but this is not the default behavior?

Comment: The default behavior is that the array items are whatever you place into the array. e.g. only strings, integers, etc. In this case it only takes `CGColorRef`, which is what the `CGColor` method returns. `AnyObject` would be any mix of types, so long as they are `AnyObject` compatible, rather than a single type. As the bridging requires the ability to move the array type to `AnyObject`, declaring it as such from the get go gets us over the Objective-C bridging issue.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot to absorb with Swift and it's going to evolve over the next several months. I'm guessing the Objective-C bridge is going to have a fair number of gotchas for the time being... I'd suggest to try playing with arrays by creating a variable array of strings and then trying to add an integer. Then, declare the array as taking `AnyObject` and see what happens. Also, checkout the Integrating Swift with Objective-C and the Swift Interoperability In Depth talks at https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ The system frameworks are still Objective-C frameworks....

Comment: thanks but later I realized that the gradient function I was using is pretty strange. Even it being a ObjC object the gradient color is defined in CGColorRef what means that the gradient drawing methos is, as expected, written in C as most of Quartz so, the gradient itself appears to be just a ObjC wrapper to C. I feel that this swift change is the first step to merge iOS and OSX in terms of frameworks. It is unproductive having NSColor/UIColor, NSRect/CGRect and stuff like that.

Answer (score 19):

This runtime error can also be triggered if it tries to bridge an array of type `[MySwiftProtocol]` over to Objective-C.

The solution is to mark your protocol with `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol MySwiftProtocol {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I extended an Objective-C class to conform to a Swift protocol, and was unable to bridge an array of that class type to the protocol type until doing this. The error I had was slightly different: "fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C".

Answer (score 4):

I found that I could fix the problem by explicitly using CGColorRef rather than CGColor for my colours, e.g.:

```
    var bottomColour:CGColorRef = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    var topColour:CGColorRef = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 123.0/255.0, blue: 37.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    gradientLayer.colors = [bottomColour, topColour]
```

...worked fine, without any NSArray or AnyObject casting. If I take out the explicit CGColorRef in the type declarations for the colours, I get the "array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C" error.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Should be the actual answer for this question

Answer (score 3):

With Swift arrays, you can call `bridgeToObjectiveC()` on them, and they'll turn into NSArrays. The same is true of Swift dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to get this to work in Swift, you can do the following:

```
let arrayColors: NSArray = [UIColor.blackColor().CGColor as AnyObject, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor as AnyObject]
```

I noticed that in my Objective-C code that I was casting the CGColorRef types to id. Not sure why though. If anyone has a reason why that would be great!

Comment: The reason why `CGColorRef` can be bridged to `id` is because `CGColorRef` can use Objective C/Cocoa retain-release functions. Under Objective C/ARC, this would need to be bridged, but Swift can handle the memory of a CoreFoundation object automatically.