# "[AnyObject]" is not identical to "NSArray"

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

Signature of a objective-c function i've used in the past is:

```
- (MMCall *)getLocalizedAppCategoriesWithOptions:(MMOptions *)options
                          success:(void (^)(NSArray *response))success
                          failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

I use to call it as -

```
[[whateverclassname new] getLocalizedAppCategoriesWithOptions:nil
                                                        success:^(NSArray *response) {
    }   failure:[^(NSError *error) {
}
```

It returns an NSArray of objects. These objects' parent class is NSObject and they have few properties.
While experimenting with swift, i updated the bridging header file with the respective header file. Issues are -

1. If I call it following way, i get compile error as "'[AnyObject]' is not identical to 'NSArray'"

   ```
   whateverclassname().getLocalizedAppCategoriesWithOptions(nil, success: {(response : NSArray!) in
       }, failure: {(error: NSError!)  in
   })
   ```
2. If I call it following way, it compiles successfully but app crashes at runtime -

   ```
   whateverclassname().getLocalizedAppCategoriesWithOptions(nil, success: {(response : [AnyObject]!) in
       }, failure: {(error: NSError!)  in
   })
   ```

Please help me find out what's wrong with this?

Comment: What message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: There is no msg as such. But threads shows objc_exception_throw after [_NSArrayM insertObjectAtindex:]

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113354/swift-array-element-cannot-be-bridged-to-objective-c/24113484#24113484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer to both of my questions -

1. Since NSArray is immutable and [AnyObject] is Array type in Swift that's mutable, compiler complains they are not identical. I changed NSArray! to Array! in Swift code. Other option is was to change Objective-C code to `success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *response))success` (not preferred as it kills the purpose of using the bridge).
2. Cast the Array to NSMuatableArray before calling the block in Objective-C

Comment: You should also use generic array so that Swift can receive a concrete array type.