# Swift Array downcasting runtime error when using a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my setup:

```
protocol Client {
    var identifier: NSUUID { get }
}

class PeripheralClient: NSObject, Client { 
    var identifier: NSUUID {
        get {
            return peripheral.identifier
        }
    }
}

protocol NetworkManager {
    var clients: [Client] { get set }
}

class CentralNetworkManager: NSObject, NetworkManager {
    var clients = [Client]()
    var peripheralClients: [PeripheralClient] {
        get {
            return clients as [PeripheralClient]
        }
    }
}
```

I get this runtime error when the `peripheralClients` Array is accessed for the first time: **array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C**.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24113484/797767) to a question with a similar error, it looks like swift requires the items in an Array to be `AnyObject` compatible when converting to `NSArray`. So that means Swift's Array typecasting is using NSArray, thus making it impossible for me to downcast from an Array whose type is a protocol.

Anyone have a good suggestion for getting around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try declaring `Client` as an Objective-C protocol?

```
@objc protocol Client {
    var identifier: NSUUID { get }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems, Swift itself does not have `Array<T>` to `Array<U>` casting functionality, it uses Obj-C facility.

Instead, to avoid that, you can cast each elements, using `map` for example:

```
var clients = [Client]()
var peripheralClients: [PeripheralClient] {
    get {
        return clients.map { $0 as PeripheralClient }
    }
}
```