# "fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C"—Why are you even trying, Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have declared a Swift protocol:

```
protocol Option {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

I declare multiple implementations of this protocol—some classes, some enums.

I have a view controller with a property declared as so:

```
var options: [Option] = []
```

When I try and set this property to an array of objects that implement the `Option` protocol in another VC's `prepareForSegue`, I get a runtime error:

```
fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C
```

Why doesn't this work? The compiler has all the information it needs, and I don't understand what Objective-C has to do with it at all—my project contains only Swift files, and these arrays aren't coming in or out of any framework methods that would necessitate them being bridged to `NSArray`.

Comment: Did you try to prepend `@objc` to your protocol? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28029568/377369

Comment: That doesn't work if any of the protocol implementations is an enum: "Non-class type 'Foo' cannot conform to class protocol 'Option'"

Comment: Why must it be a class protocol though? I'm not passing it to an Obj-C framework or anything else that requires the Swift Array to be bridged to NSArray.

Comment: They way Swift and Objective-C work together is still a secret to me. I just have to "accept" many things which just "work" or "don't work".

Comment: Why does this one have so many downvotes? Looks like a fair and clear question to me.

Comment: Note that I'm not the only one having issues with this: http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/521

Comment: I got this entirely in Swift code (though in a class derived from NSObject), when passing from a function taking an array of a concrete type to an function taking an array of optionals of that same type.  This feels like a bug in the compiler's static analysis in the area of array covariance.  I fixed it by making sure there was no difference in optionality of the array element types.

Comment: For the record, I've finally gotten around to updating the project concerned to Swift 3.0(.1) and it seems the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is quite... *unsatisfying*, but it works. Where I set the array on the destination view controller I do:

```
destinationViewController.options = options.map({$0 as Option})
```

Comment: can't you cast whole array? `options as [Option]`

Comment: Nope. Tried it (Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002)), doesn't work. I shouldn't *need* to cast it in any case, the compiler knows I'm passing in an Array of things that implement Option.

Comment: "an Array of things that implement Option" Ah, but that is not the same as an Array of Option, which is what you need. See my answer.

Comment: This works, and yes it is very unsatisfying... this should not be needed. Swift should be able to handle htis.

Comment: I concur...it works this way, but it is a very unsatisfying bit of code

Answer (score 22):

> the compiler knows I'm passing in an Array of things that implement Option

You've let slip there a very revealing remark, which suggests the source of the issue. An "Array of things that implement Option" is not an Array of Option.

The problem is with the type of `options` back at the point where you create it (in `prepareForSegue`). You don't show that code, but I am betting that you fail to cast / type it at that point. That's why the assignment fails. `options` may be an array of things that do in fact happen to adopt Option, but that's not enough; it must be *typed* as an array of Option.

So, back in `prepareForSegue`, form your `options` like this:

```
let options : [Option] = // ... whatever ...
```

*Now* you will be able to assign it directly to `destinationViewController.options`.

Here's a quick test case (in a playground; I detest playgrounds, but they can have their uses):

```
protocol Option {
    var name : String {get}
}

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var options : [Option] = []
}

enum Thing : Option {
    var name : String {
        get {
            return "hi"
        }
    }
    case Thing
}

let vc = ViewController()
let options : [Option] = [Thing.Thing]
vc.options = options // no problem
```

(I also tested this in an actual app with an actual `prepareForSegue`, and it works fine.)

Comment: I think this is broken in the extreme because the compiler *does* know at runtime that Thing is an Option. And in any case, as noted in the comment to my own answer below, neither casting (`viewController.options = things as [Option]`) nor creating a temp variable explicitly typed as `[Option]` as you suggest here, actually works. In both cases I get the runtime error.

Comment: Then you have to explain why it works for me. Something else is going on that you have not stated. If you do not reveal more code, I simply have to suspect that you are holding back something essential.

Comment: Maybe. But I'm still confused as to what this has to do with Objective-C in the first place (vis. the original runtime error.) I'm not doing anything (that I can see) which ought to force a bridging cast to NSArray.

Comment: I might be able to say more about that if I could see more of your of code.

Comment: By definition, I don't know which parts to show you because I don't know what parts are relevant.

Comment: Look at it this way. I've shown you code that works. You have _not_ shown me code that _doesn't_ work - I cannot reproduce your issue from the data given. Help me reproduce it.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original problem.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  The message thrown by Xcode should be considered a bug, though (and a better message should be displayed by Xcode).

Comment: I think the code in this answer only works because the right hand side of the assignment `let options: [Option] = [Thing.Thing]` is a literal. If it had been an array of type `[Thing]`, it would not have worked. Maybe this is the problem the OP ran into. Personally, I have solved the problem for me through generic functions that use the protocol as a type constraint.

Comment: This issue is still not fixed, the discussion is insane, never saw a language that can't handle it. Isn't this what protocols are for, to use it instead the concrete class? This would mean you also can't assign an object that was declared as a protocol

Comment: No, i'm still on the stable version, is it fixed in swift3?

Comment: @CristiBăluță That is what you would need to find out before claiming "this issue is still not fixed"

Comment: Seems to be fixed with Swift 3.0.1 for my original case.

Comment: @RobertAtkins Yes, there's a whole new way of bridging arrays to Objective-C, at last.

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem and fixed it marking my protocol with `@objc`, in your case it would look like this

```
@objc protocol Option {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Got the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28029568/1801237)

Comment: As in the comments on the original question, this doesn't work if any of the implementors of the protocol are Swift Enums. Which in my case they are.

Comment: typo obcj should be  objc

Answer (score 1):

This one also works fine

```
destinationViewController.options = options.map{$0}
```