# Objective-C Bridge NSArray Crash

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsarray

I'm trying to send some data from a swift file to an objective-c file. I have all the bridging headers and whatnot configured, such that when I pass a string, it can be used by the objective-c file. However, I would really like to pass an NSArray, and when I do this, I get a whole slew of errors starting with

```
[Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000363a0
```

I saw [Array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113354/array-element-cannot-be-bridged-to-objective-c) but solutions on that page, which were switching the Array to an NSArray in swift, and making all the objects in the array AnyObjects, did not work; besides, the error I got is different from the error on the aforementioned question. This is my condensed code:

Swift:

```
var myNSArray = ["foo","bar"]
objectiveCClassInstance.arrayPassFunction(myNSArray)
```

.h:

```
- (void)arrayPassFunction:(NSArray*)myObjectiveCNSArray;
```

.m:

```
- (void)arrayPassFunction:(NSArray*)myObjectiveCNSArray{
    NSLog(myObjectiveCNSArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `NSLog` is incorrect. The first parameter of `NSLog` is the format string. You meant:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myObjectiveCNSArray);
```

I'm surprised you didn't get a warning about this.

Comment: The compiler does issue a "warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)"

Comment: Right; that's exactly the problem. You must make sure that ObjC code has no warnings. I generally recommend turning on "treat warnings as errors."

Comment: ... and turning on almost all warnings.