# Swift protocol property using AnyObject - array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm not sure if we can declare a protocol like:

```
protocol UIProtocol {
    var height: CGFloat {get set}
}
protocol myProtocol : UIProtocol {
    var item: AnyObject? {get set}
}
```

And then if I init an array of [myProtocol], this will give me:
**array cannot be bridged from Objective-C**

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Marking the protocol as `@objc` will fix it. For more details, see this discussion: [Array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113354/array-element-cannot-be-bridged-to-objective-c)